# How do I access .Net objects in another process?

Tags: .net, wcf, process, components

I have a .Net app running.

I want another .Net app to connect the the first app and call public methods on one of its objects.

I know I can do this via WCF, but my understanding is that .Net objects are all components in the COM sense, and so I assume can be marshalled across process boundaries on the same machine.

Is this possible? And if so how do I get hold of the object in the first app from the second?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I should clarify that I know they are not COM visible objects. I meant that they are distinct components in the same sense that a COM object is a component.

Comment: http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2010/02/blazing-fast-ipc-in-net-4-wcf-vs.html may be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object that inherits from [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) can be accessed across process boundaries (this is different from being COM visible though).  This is what wcf will use under the bonnet.

However, if you use wcf instead of (lower-level) Remoting then you allow the long-term option of crossing machine boundaries  (remoting does allow you to do this too, but it's even more convoluted than wcf... **edit** - and less secure too, as noted in the link provided by daniel in the comments below).

In short, I agree with Daniel - you're better off sticking with WCF - for future options and ease of use.

Comment: Please elaborate on the part that the objects can be accessed across process boundaries. What would you use to achieve this?

Comment: .Net remoting is what Nathan is talking about.

Comment: ah. Which is in fact superseded by WCF and should not be used any more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not correct. By default, .NET classes are no COM objects. You can, however, make them COM visible, either on a per class basis or for the whole assembly.
Having said that, this is not going to help you, because the COM objects are running in-proc with the process that uses them, i.e. it runs in your second application. You can't connect to another application like this.
You really should use WCF to accomplish this task.